# C# adding empty row to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Small issue I'm having with my code I can't fix. I have a GridView with a ImageButton which should add a new empty row. For some reason I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    CTI_DFC.Default.gv_Steps_RowCommand(Object sender,
>   GridViewCommandEventArgs e) +469
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean
>   causesValidation, String validationGroup) +172
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e) +163    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +83
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3771

So this is the GridView I have:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_Steps" runat="server" CssClass="lbl_user" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10px" HeaderStyle-Height="23.5px" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
    RowStyle-Height="23.5px" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" style="z-index: 1; left: 8px; top: 143px; position: absolute; height: 20px; width: 1178px;" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gv_Steps_RowCommand">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCE4FF" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Step" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Step" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%# Bind("Step") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Server" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Server" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%# Bind("Server") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Type" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%# Bind("Type") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Job" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%# Bind("Job") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Number" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%# Bind("Number") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="15px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_AddRow" runat="server" AlternateText="Add Row" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="Add" ImageUrl="./Img/ADD.png" ToolTip="Add Row without Change" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="15px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_DeleteRow" runat="server" AlternateText="Delete Row" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="./Img/DEL.png" ToolTip="Delete Row without Change" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0B4DA2" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle Height="23px" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And this is the C# code how I'm trying to do it:

```
protected void gv_Steps_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int intIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);  //will be used for Delete

    if (e.CommandName == "Delete" && (gv_Steps.Rows.Count > 1))
    {
        //Nothing done yet
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "Add")
    {
        DataTable dt = gv_Steps.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        gv_Steps.DataSource = dt;
        gv_Steps.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice!

**EDIT**

I understand now that my DataTable is empty and doesn't work like that, but how can I get GridView to DataSet and back with new empty row? I tried it like this with same error:

```
protected void gv_Steps_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int intIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);  //will be used for Delete

        if (e.CommandName == "Delete" && (gv_Steps.Rows.Count > 1))
        {
            //Nothing done yet
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "Add")
        {
            DataTable dt = GridviewToDataTable();
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            gv_Steps.DataSource = dt;
            gv_Steps.DataBind();
        }
    }

private DataTable GridviewToDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Step", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Server", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Job", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Number", typeof(string)));

        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_Steps.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][0] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Step")).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][1] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Server")).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][2] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Type")).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][3] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Job")).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][4] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Number")).Text;
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Error i get:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    CTI_DFC.Default.GridviewToDataTable() +1161
>   CTI_DFC.Default.gv_Steps_RowCommand(Object sender,
>   GridViewCommandEventArgs e) +392
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean
>   causesValidation, String validationGroup) +172
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e) +163    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +83
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3771

**EDIT 2**

Tried it like this:

```
protected void gv_Steps_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int intIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);  //will be used for Delete

        if (e.CommandName == "Delete" && (gv_Steps.Rows.Count > 1))
        {
            //Nothing done yet
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "Add")
        {
            DataTable dt = GridviewToDataTable(gv_Steps);
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            gv_Steps.DataSource = dt;
            gv_Steps.DataBind();
            GridviewToDataTable(gv_Steps);
        }
    }
private DataTable GridviewToDataTable(GridView gv)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Step", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Server", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Job", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Number", typeof(string)));
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][0] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Step")).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][1] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Server")).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][2] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Type")).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][3] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Job")).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][4] = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Number")).Text;
        }
        gv.DataSource = dt;
        gv.DataBind();
        return dt;
    }
```

Error I get:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    CTI_DFC.Default.GridviewToDataTable(GridView gv) +1145
>   CTI_DFC.Default.gv_Steps_RowCommand(Object sender,
>   GridViewCommandEventArgs e) +407
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean
>   causesValidation, String validationGroup) +172
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e) +163    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +83
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3771

Any other advice?

**SOLUTION**

I did it, got it done like this:

```
private DataTable GridviewToDataTable(GridView gv)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Step", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Server", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Job", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Number", typeof(string)));
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][0] = (row.FindControl("txt_Step") as TextBox).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][1] = (row.FindControl("txt_Server") as TextBox).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][2] = (row.FindControl("txt_Type") as TextBox).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][3] = (row.FindControl("txt_Job") as TextBox).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][4] = (row.FindControl("txt_Number") as TextBox).Text;
        }
        lbl_Fehlermeldung.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        lbl_Fehlermeldung.Visible = true;
        gv.DataSource = dt;
        gv.DataBind();
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: `gv_Steps.DataSource` only works on initial load, not on PostBack.

Answer (score 1):

Your Datasource is empty, this why your DataTable is converted to null object, and exception is throwed

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get my GridView to DataTable and back? See my Edit how i tried it..

Comment: can you show the exception after your edit?

Comment: Sorry forgot that one, added it.

Comment: your gv_Steps object is null, maybe try to bind it again to datasource or hold it as global object

Comment: Tried to bind it again, failed. What do you mean exactly with "hold it as global object"? With Session[] or?

Comment: Session or static

Comment: Can you give me an example with static please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good for Empty `gridview` only. As you do not increment the row index.

For adding new row to the `gridview` has some concern.

Do you previously have some `datasource` in the `gridview` or not ? If you have some `datasource` previously and then you need to save the `datasource` in `viewstate` and before adding a new row you need to extract previous data in the `gridview` and then add a new row.

Follow below code

***First set initial row save `datasource` in `viewstate`

```
private void SetInitialRow()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
    dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    //dr = dt.NewRow();

    //Store the DataTable in ViewState
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

    Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

***set it in `page_load`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SetInitialRow(); 
    }
}
```

*** Add new row to `gridview`

```
private void AddNewRowToGrid()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;

    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //extract the TextBox values
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                rowIndex++;
            }
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

            Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }

    //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
    SetPreviousData();
}
```

***Set previous data

```
private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();

                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*** call on button click

```
 protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }
```

Sorce link https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-new-Row-to-GridView-on-Button-Click-in-ASPNet.aspx